# Android Bluetooth Turn OFF While Connecting

Tags: android, bluetooth

Apparently Android 5.0 and higher have messed up the use of Bluetooth LE and I need to create a workaround for it.
What I have noticed is that the time to Connect to a discovered device is LONG.
However if the Bluetooth Service is turned OFF and then ON, it generally will Connect faster.

The app I am working on needs to run on Android 4.3 and higher.
Typically I just launch the   **BluetoothGatt.connect()**  and all is good.
But with the Android 5.0+ the Connect() launches, but stays there a LONG TIME before finalizing the action.

With that in mind I put in a  **Handler().postDelayed()** routine with a 10 second timeout to look to 'see' if the Connection has successfully completed.
If the Connection has not finalized I want to programatically Turn OFF the phone's Bluetooth service entirely and then Turn it ON again.

However when I attempt to execute **BluetoothAdapter.disable()**  the app crashes.
I can only guess that is because the BluetoothGatt.connect() activity is still attempting to complete in the background (via the BluetoothLEService).

I can manually turn OFF the phone's Bluetooth Service regardless of its 'condition' and it works.
So how can I programatically shut OFF the phone's Bluetooth service while a Connect() attempt is still attempting to execute - basically a **TURN OFF NOW**

Your suggestions/advice would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well with a lot of trial & error I found a sequence that appears to work.
Within  **my Handler().postDelayed()**  I now have the following code

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      if (!mConnected && !paymentDone && myOSVersionNum >= 5.0) {
          mBluetoothLeService.initialize();
          mBluetoothLeService.disconnect();
          BluetoothAdapter myBTadapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
          myBTadapter.disable();
          while (myBTadapter.isEnabled()){
            // Wait Here Until DISABLED
          }
          // Now Turn Back ON & Re-Connect
          myBTadapter.enable();
          mBluetoothLeService.connect(mDeviceAddress);
       }
      }
    }, 6000);   // 6 Seconds  (6,000 Milliseconds)
```

I am sure that others will find problems with the approach I ended up with and, hopefully, critique it towards a better method.

In spite of that, I don't know if this will be of any assistance to anyone else, but it seems as though I had to:
1. Terminate the Service action ( initialize() & disconnect() )
2. Define a new BT Adapter (the existing, original definition wouldn't work)
3. Utilize the new BT Adapter to begin again.